# UV unwrap doesn't affect the texture on my model

Tags: uv

I have already uv unwrapped my model (to not the best possible result perhaps, but I've done it) and in order to test it, I have applied a material with brick texture to my model. But the texture on my model remains unchanged, as if no unwrapping has been done.
What am I getting wrong?
I seem to be missing something although i don't really understand what.
Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need a Texture Coordinate node in your material setting the Brick Texture node's Vector input to UV:

[image]

Without that the Vector input's default is Generated:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response, it was the most helpful.

Comment: Glad to hear it!  If I've answered your question I'd appreciate it if you'd click the checkmark next to my answer.